# Create Web Service (WCF) that return an acknowledgement and return the actual result by calling client API

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf

I need to create a webservice that return an acknowledgement of the call and data passed before proceeding with the actual operation.

When finish. I need to call client web service by passing the actual result of the operation. Is there any way to accomplished this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to accomplish that would be to employ [duplex services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064(v=vs.110).aspx) that allow two-way commucation.
When a client calls such a service, it also provides a callback (defined for this service) that the service can employ to call the client as it needs.

Note, that this communication model places some restrictions on how such a service works, is declared and implemented.